# Batch file to check if a certain file exists

Tags: batch-file, cmd

```
d:
IF EXIST D:\JDK Folder\bin\awt.dll (echo youhavejava) ELSE (echo youdonthavejava)
pause
```

I wanted to make this program to check if a file exists on my computer or not and it will tell me the answer. I have tried to get this code to work, but no matter what I do it won't work. Can someone please tell me what the problem is? All it does is run and not output anything.

Comment: Put quotation marks around the path...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need quotes around the file path, because there is a space in it.

```
IF EXIST "D:\JDK Folder\bin\awt.dll" (echo youhavejava) ELSE (echo youdonthavejava)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! You really helped me!

Comment: Doesn't work for me: 

if exist "%~dp0\report.afr" (
echo file found
reporter_tool ^
%~dp0\report.afr ^
--reporter=xml:outfile=%~dp0\original_report.xml
) else (
echo report file is not found
)

Comment: It seems like yours is a different problem. Do you have report.afr in the same folder as the batch file? What is the error?

Answer (score -1):

Unless you want a custom message, an easy way of achieving this is to use dir.
This message will also be useful for checking if certain folders exist, and not just files.

Example:

```
dir C:\Users\Username\Desktop\RandomFile.exe
```

If the path specified is valid, it will return with

```
Volume in drive C has no label.
Volume Serial Number is xxx

Directory of C:\Users\Username\Desktop
```

And  then it will specify stuff like the file name, dates, etc.

If the file or path does not exist, it will return with

```
File Not Found
```

Comment: I was hoping to use the "if" command for this because I wanted to make a program were if a certain program is on your computer, it will say that the program is on there, and otherwise, it will install the program for you.

Comment: This will only check for a directory, not file